# how to stop navigation inside text box using keyboard up and down key while navigating in the suggestion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text box, where on click or type of words user will see some suggestions, problem is while suggestions are visible and navigating to the suggestion using up/down key inside text box also its navigating

Below is the code :

```
<label>when</label>
                        <div class="fl">
                            <input class="date-field startdate cornerall" type="text"/>
                            <div class="input-wrapper">
                            <input type="text" class="starttime cornerall" placeholder="Add a Time?"/>
                            <div class="dropdown stsugstn hidden">
                            <ul class="result cornerall">
                                <li class="sugactive">11.05</li>
                                <li>11.05</li>
                                <li>11.05</li>
                                <li>11.05</li>
                                <li>11.05</li>
                            </ul>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#" class="timezone title-tip" title="IST">GMT+5:30</a>
                            <a href="#" class="endtimeln">End Time?</a>               
                        </div>
```

respective jquery:

```
$('.cnewrap').on({
        keyup: function(e){
            var $this = $(this);
            var $vl = $this.val();
            var $st = $this.parent().find('.stsugstn');
            var key = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            if($vl != null && $vl.length > 0){
                if($st.hasClass( "hidden" )){
                    $st.removeClass('hidden');
                }
                if (key === 38 || key === 40){
                    //TODO write code to stop navigation inside text box
                    //$this.val($vl);
                }
            }else{
                if(!$st.hasClass( "hidden" )){
                    $st.addClass('hidden');
                }

            }
        },
        click: function(e){
            var $this = $(this);
            var $vl = $this.val();
            var $st = $this.parent().find('.stsugstn');
            if($vl != null && $vl.length > 0 && $st.hasClass( "hidden" )){
                $st.removeClass('hidden');
            }

        }
    },'.starttime');
```

jquery for navigating between suggestions:

```
$(window).on('keyup', function(e){
        var $stsugstn = $('.stsugstn');
        var $etsugstn = $('.etsugstn');
        var $next = '';
        var key = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if($stsugstn!= null && $stsugstn.length > 0 && !$stsugstn.hasClass( "hidden" )){
            var $current = $('.stsugstn ul li.sugactive');
            if (key === 38){
                if($current.is(':first-child')){
                    $next = $('.stsugstn ul li:last-child');
                }else{

                    $next = $current.prev();
                }
            }
            if (key === 40){
                if($current.is(':last-child')){
                    $next = $('.stsugstn ul li:first-child');
                }else{
                    $next = $current.next();
                }
            }

            if ($next.length > 0) {
                $current.removeClass('sugactive');
                $next.addClass('sugactive');
            }
        }
        if($etsugstn!= null && $etsugstn.length > 0 && !$etsugstn.hasClass( "hidden" )){
            var $current = $('.etsugstn ul li.sugactive');
            if (key === 38){
                if($current.is(':first-child')){
                    $next = $('.etsugstn ul li:last-child');
                }else{

                    $next = $current.prev();
                }
            }
            if (key === 40){
                if($current.is(':last-child')){
                    $next = $('.etsugstn ul li:first-child');
                }else{
                    $next = $current.next();
                }
            }

            if ($next.length > 0) {
                $current.removeClass('sugactive');
                $next.addClass('sugactive');
            }
        }
    });
```

please suggest me how I can stop navigating inside textbox while navigating inside suggestion using up/down key
as suggested for jsfiddle,
here is the link
http://jsfiddle.net/Brg9t/

Comment: a fiddle would help, but.. Well.. maybe calling e.preventDefault() would work when you detect the key is up/down..

Comment: I tried with e.preventDefault() but it didn't work for me..rather I put return false; which seems worked but it stopped navigation between suggestions

Comment: so return false kind of works.. where did you put return false?

Comment: @user1600124: inside the textbox query i.e where I marked as //TODO

Comment: please put it in fiddle

Comment: @jarvanJiang : created http://jsfiddle.net/Brg9t/

Comment: You can move the logic to navigate suggestions to the //todo part before return false. Or make the logic into a function to call in the //todo part. When you return false, you are preventing the other handler from being invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigger your event in `keydown`,that's because the browser behavior is already done in `keyup`,neither `preventDefault` or `return false` will not work that time.

So change `keyup` to `keydown`,and add `return false` in the //todo part will be ok.
See fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Brg9t/1/.

Comment: Make sense seems textbox navigation is stopped, but introduce one more concern, if you will see in the fiddle suggestion is not appearing on first time enter i.e if I will enter 1 its not appearing but if I type again 1 its appearing..any help on the same

Comment: Thanks I have added keyup and keydown both, in keyup just showing the suggestion and keydown returning false..it seems worked ...thanks for your help :)